# Evaluate $\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {8^{2k+3}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

> Evaluate $$\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {8^{2k+3}}$$

So  far, I was able to get to
$$\frac{1}{64}\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {1} {8^{2k}\cdot2^{4k}}$$
And then I'm completely stuck.

Comment: $8 = 2^3$, and join both twos.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $8^{2k}\cdot 2^{4k} = (64\cdot 16)^k = 1,024^k$

Answer (score 0):

Note $8=2^3$, so 
$$\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {8^{2k+3}}=\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {2^{3(2k+3)}}=\sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {2^{6k+9}}=\sum_{k=400}^{2000}2^{-10k-6}$$

and this is a geometric sequence with first term $2^{-4006}$ and ratio $2^{-10}$. Solve it using the formula

$$S=a\left(\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}\right)$$
where $a$ is the first term, $n$ is the number of terms, and $r$ is the common ratio.

Comment: Great, thanks. But when I input $2^{-4006}$ into my calculator I get 0, making everything zero.

Comment: Well yes, the answer is extremely close to zero.

Comment: So my answer would be zero then? I see no way of making the calculator give me a different answer.

Comment: Your calculator doesn't necessarily give the right answer. That's why you're not supposed do depend on it. Try calculating the sum yourself, and get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Well, I got to $ \frac {1}{64x2^{2406}}$
And I'm fairly sure I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\large \sum_{k=400}^{2000} \frac {2^{3-4k}} {8^{2k+3}}
&=\large\sum_{k=400}^{2000}2^{3-4k-3(2k+3)}\\
&=\large\sum_{k=400}^{2000}2^{-10k-6}\\
&=\large\frac 1{2^6}\sum_{k=400}^{2000}\frac 1{2^{10k}}\\
&=\large\frac 1{2^6}\sum_{k=400}^{2000}{u^{k}}\quad \text{where $u=\large \frac 1{2^{10}}$}\\
&=\large\frac 1{2^6}\frac {u^{400}(1-u^{1601})}{1-u}\\
&=\large\large\frac 1{2^6}\frac {\frac 1{2^{4000}}{(1-\frac 1{2^{16010}})}}{1-\frac 1{2^{10}}}\\
&=\large\frac {\frac 1{2^{3996}}{(1-\frac 1{2^{16010}})}}{2^{10}-1}\\
\end{align}$$
...it does look rather messy...